# Error in DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I want to rearrange the format of my DateTime and save it in a DateTime dataType.

Codes:

```
string _date = 2015-08-26 08:00;
DateTime y = Convert.ToDateTime(_date); //Output: 8/26/2015 8:00:00 AM
DateTime selectedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Expected Output **2015-08-26 09:00:00** *yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss*

I tried this:

```
DateTime selectedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Error: Additional information: DateTime pattern 'm' appears more than once with different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For month, use `MM` and also your date has no seconds so also need to remove `ss`

Try this

```
string _date = 2015-08-26 08:00;
DateTime selectedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

/*
    dd -> two digit day
    MM -> two digit month
    yyyy -> four digit year
    hh -> two digit hour (AM/PM) and HH for 00-24
    mm -> two digit minute
    ss -> two digit seconds
*/
```

Comment: Result: **8/26/2015 8:00:00 AM** No Error thou but not my expected output

Comment: @MeSoftware Do you need date time again into string formated?

Comment: @MeSoftware The `selectedDate1` is of `DateTime` type and it show you date time according to your culture selected in your PC calendar settings

Comment: @MeSoftware Use `selectedDate1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` to get back string formated date.

Comment: I'm saving it to database {DateTime Format must be yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss}. If I try using toString(); it will be converted to string datatype and I need a DateTime datatype.

Comment: @MeSoftware You need just save `selectedDate1` into database.

Comment: Database server will convert it into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` automatically if you field is DateTime type

Comment: Okay Thanks... I'll Delete post. Did not try it sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Its the difference between month for `MM` and minutes for `mm`.

Comment: Error: Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.